# python 3: lists dont change their values

Tags: python, list

So I am trying to change a bunch of list items by a random percentage using a for loop.

```
import random as rdm
list = [1000, 100, 50, 25]
def change():
    for item in list:
        item = item + item*rdm.uniform(-10, 10)
change()
print(list)
```

(also I dont get how to paste multiple lines of code so I did them one by one, would appreciate help with that too)
And now when it prints the list it only consists of the numbers it started with.

Comment: None of your lines of code mutate the list.

Comment: oh ok. how do i fix it though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `item =`.... line, as it stands, just associates a new object with the name `item` in the function's namespace.  There is no reason why this operation would change the content of the list object from which the *previous* value of `item` was extracted.

Here is a listing that changes a list in-place:

```
import random
lyst = [1000,100,50,25]
def change(lyst):
    for i, item in enumerate(lyst):
        item = item + item * random.uniform(-10, 10)
        lyst[i] = item

print(lyst)
change(lyst)
print(lyst)
```

The `lyst[i] =`... assignment is the key line that actually changes the list's content.  Of course you can collapse the two assignments into one line if you want: `lyst[i] = item =`.....   Or you can omit the reassignment to `item` if you're not going to use it again in the loop: `lyst[i] = item + item *`...

Note that I performed two minor fixes in addition:  I changed the variable name from `list` to `lyst` so that it doesn't overshadow your builtin reference to the `list` class.  I have also altered your function so that it takes the list object as an argument, rather than relying on referring to it using a hard-coded global variable name. Both of these are just good practice; nothing to do with your problem.

Finally, note that you can do all of this much more succinctly and transparently with a so-called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).  If you don't have to modify the list in-place, i.e. if it's OK to end up with a modified *copy* of the original list:

```
lyst = [ item + item * random.uniform(-10, 10)  for item in lyst ]
```

If you need to modify the list in-place (e.g. if other references to the original list exist elsewhere and they, too, should point to the updated content after `change()` is called) then you can follow the suggestion in Padraic's comment:

```
lyst[:] = [ item + item * random.uniform(-10, 10)  for item in lyst ]
```

In that last case, you can even save memory (which will only be a concern for very large lists) if you change the bracket shape and thereby use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) instead:

```
lyst[:] = ( item + item * random.uniform(-10, 10)  for item in lyst )
```

Comment: I hate `lyst` - `items` sounds much better

Comment: I think `lst` might be a better name,`lst[:] = ...` can also change the original object

Comment: In read-only situations I usually call it `seq`, but `items` would do equally well. Here, though, the input argument *must* be a list or other mutable container rather than, say, a tuple, so a reminder of that fact, like `lyst` or Padraic's `lst`, is probably a good choice.  I will make a note of Apryllyon's hatred of `lyst`, however.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the computed value back to the list.

So replace:

```
for item in list:
    item = item + item*rdm.uniform(-10, 10)
```

With:

```
for index, item in enumerate(list):
    list[index] = item + item*rdm.uniform(-10, 10);
```

With the modified loop, you will be looping through each element in the list with its index. You can now assign back the computed value to that particular index in the list.

Answer (score 0):

using functional approach and list comprehensions instead of for loop, you can create a new list with the changed items (unless you NEED to modify the existing list in place):

```
import random as rdm
items = [1000, 100, 50, 25]

def change(items, multiply_min=-10, multiply_max=10):
    return [i * rdm.uniform(multiply_min, multiply_max) for i in items]

items = change(items)
print(items)
```

Comment: That's probably the neatest way to do it, *but* it should be noted that it's a solution to a problem that, strictly, is different from the one in the OP's question (the OP was talking about modifying an existing list, and that's different if references to the original list are also stored elsewhere)