# Replacing string element in for loop Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am reading data in from a text file so each row is a list of strings, and all those lists are in a data list. So my lists look like:

```
data = [row1, row2, etc.]
row1 = [str1, str2, etc.]
```

I am trying to remove any $ or % signs that appear in the strings in a row list. I have checked that if I try and do this for one individual element, say the second row and the fourth element has a "%", so:

```
data[1][3] = data[1][3].replace("%","")
```

This will properly remove it, but when I try and use a nested for loop to do it all:

```
for row in data:
    for x in row:
        x = x.replace("%","")
        x = x.replace("$","")
```

This doesn't remove any of the % or $ signs, I have tried just doing it without the second replace to see if it would at least remove the % signs, but even that didn't work.

Any ideas why this wouldn't work, or how I could do this?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please do not use `str` as a name for a variable in Python. It is also a function!

Comment: `for-in` doesn't affect the actual list because the element is stored/copied into a variable, it's not a direct reference. Use enumerate and access list.

Comment: I will update, I don't actually have it that way in my code I just wrote it that way for clarity.

Comment: @CRT I also editted to show the second issue with code and a simple remedy using enumerate().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your *str* variable is shadowing the builtin Python [*str*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#str) variable.  That fix is easy.  Just use another variable name.

The second problem is that the replaced string isn't being replaced in the row list itself.  The fix is to save the replaced string back into the *row* list.  For that, you can use [*enumerate()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#enumerate) to give you both the value and its position in the row:

```
for row in data:
    for i, x in enumerate(row):
        x = x.replace("%","")
        x = x.replace("$","")
        row[i] = x
```

Comment: Is that the *only* problem?

Comment: Use of the name `str` is a code smell but it wouldn't stop it from working.

Comment: I just updated it, I don't actually have it as str in my code, I was writing it that way here to try and make it clear what I was looping through.

Comment: @AndrewL. There were two problems.  I've commented on both.

Comment: Thanks, I am still new to python, so I need to look into enumerate more, but that did solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a new value to the name `x`  but that does not change the contents of `row` or `data`.  After changing `x`, you need to assign `row[j] = x` or `data[i][j] = x` for the appropriate column index `j` (and row index `i`). See also [python 3: lists dont change their values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820183/python-3-lists-dont-change-their-values)

Answer (score 0):

Also in your in this case you can use list comprehension

```
data = [[item.replace("%", "").replace("$", "0") for item in row] for row in data]
```

Comment: What are  _list expressions_? do you mean [_list comprehension_](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)?

Comment: Sure, it's my mistake. Thank you.